# Absolute and Relative matrix translation

Tags: c++, view

```
enum msoff { M00,M01,M02,M03,
             M10,M11,M12,M13,
             M20,M21,M22,M23 };

    /******************************************************************************
    ******************************************************************************
    *               Translate Matrix to Relative Position
    ******************************************************************************
*****************************************************************************/
int     phd_TranslateRel( sint32 x, sint32 y, sint32 z )
    {
    sint32  *mptr;
    mptr = phd_mxptr;
    *(mptr+M03) += *(mptr+M00)*x + *(mptr+M01)*y + *(mptr+M02)*z;
    *(mptr+M13) += *(mptr+M10)*x + *(mptr+M11)*y + *(mptr+M12)*z;
    *(mptr+M23) += *(mptr+M20)*x + *(mptr+M21)*y + *(mptr+M22)*z;

    return(1);
    }

    /******************************************************************************
    ******************************************************************************
    *               Translate Matrix to Absolute Position
    *                   returns 0 if out of range!!!
    ******************************************************************************
*****************************************************************************/


void    phd_TranslateAbs( sint32 x, sint32 y, sint32 z )
    {
    sint32  *mptr = phd_mxptr;

    x -= *(w2v_matrix+M03);          /* Subtract Position Of */
    y -= *(w2v_matrix+M13);          /* W2V Matrix  */
    z -= *(w2v_matrix+M23);

    *(mptr+M03) = *(mptr+M00)*x + *(mptr+M01)*y + *(mptr+M02)*z;
    *(mptr+M13) = *(mptr+M10)*x + *(mptr+M11)*y + *(mptr+M12)*z;
    *(mptr+M23) = *(mptr+M20)*x + *(mptr+M21)*y + *(mptr+M22)*z;
    }
```

This code from game 90s years. There is two functions for translation View matrix. I dont understand difference between then. Explain please.

Comment: I'd start by figuring out what is `w2v_matrix`.

Comment: Seems w2v_matrix+M03 w2v_matrix+M13 w2v_matrix+M23 is x,y,z view matrix position in world coordinates.

Comment: So that subtraction turns absolute coords into those relative to the camera position.

Comment: Catches my attention that the first returns 1, but the comments say nothing about it whereas the second returns void, but the comments say it returns 0 if out of range.